# How can I tell if my current thermostat wiring has a C wire?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

We just moved into a new house and I want to replace the thermostat. I am trying to figure out if my current setup has a C Wire.

If it doesn't, then I'll need to get a new wire run -- which I want to avoid.

If it helps, this is a [White Rodgers 1F80-361](https://climate.emerson.com/en-us/products/thermostats/thermostat-manuals) thermostat.

[image]

Comment: it does not need C wire, it is battery operated,

Comment: I know it is. But I am replacing the thermostat and the one I am getting needs a C Wire.

Comment: so that is the old thermostat ? it does not have the C connected to it.

Comment: I guess not? I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your furnace/HVAC unit's control board and see if there is a "C" terminal.  If so, then see which wire, if any, it's connected to.  That is your "C" wire at the thermostat.

If no "C" terminal that you will not have a "C" wire and could possibly hook one up if you have the wiring diagram for the furnace.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you show the new thermostat not the old one.

That one doe not need C- wire. It is battery operated.

It also does not have the C-wire connected in that photo.

Sometimes you get lucky and the C wire is there, just not used (probably black or blue wire.

[image: thermostat]